# Is there any way to modify installed modules in python for research purposes?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python, i am using python3.9, I've installed PyCrypt via Pip, and tried run the AES algorithm installed and included in Cipher package as follows:

> > *from Crypto.Cipher import AES*

I have 2 questions:

1. how to get the pure source code of the installed AES algorithm?
2. I am a researcher and I need to increase the number of rounds of the AES how to modify the source code?
   thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/)? It has its source [on GitHub](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean PyCrypto.
The approach depends of the OS you are using but it's for sure possible. For exemple if you are on Linux you can do :

```
pip install pyCripto
```

This will outputs the exact location of your package that you can dive to binaries to modify it.

2. By default AES has 10 rounds for 128-bit keys, 12 rounds for 192-bit keys, and 14 rounds for 256-bit keys (Key sizes: 128, 192 or 256 bits). **See this [Git](https://gist.github.com/LuoZijun/80e138446f26eb892a16) for more.**

Comment: i am on windows, and for rounds i need to increase the no. of rounds for 128bit key

Comment: If you are using Anaconda, it's gonna be on 'C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\pkgs' otherwise look for your python packages location using 'python -v' on the command line.
then importing yout package will display it's location. next you should locate that function you want to change

Comment: If it is what you where looking for please confirm answer.

Comment: @Sh.H.Murad please accept answer if it resolved your issue, otherwise you can give a feedback

Comment: i am afraid that my questions not clear enough for the others. All i want is how to get the source code of the AES cipher which is implemented in the Crypto.Cipher?